# In-App Purchase does not appear in mobile

Tags: unity, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing In-App Purchase, But it does not appear when running on mobile.

When the user clicks the In-App Purchase button then I want to open the In-App Purchase and unlock levels 11-20 (by default, levels 1-10 are free). How do I do this?

```
IapManager.cs

public class IapManager : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{
     public static IapManager Instance { set; get; }

     private Gamemanager gameLevelManager;

     void Awake()
     {
          Instance = this;
     }

     private static IStoreController m_StoreController;
     private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider;

     public static string product_10_silver = "silver10";              

     void Start()
     {
            if (m_StoreController == null)
            {
                 InitializePurchasing();
                 gameLevelManager = FindObjectOfType<Gamemanager>();

            }
      }

      public void InitializePurchasing()
      {
            if (IsInitialized())
            {
                      return;
            }
           var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
           builder.AddProduct(product_10_silver , ProductType.Consumable);
           builder.AddProduct(product_no_ads, ProductType.NonConsumable);
           UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
        }

        private bool IsInitialized()
        {

           return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
        }

        public void Buy10Silver()  //silver //11-20 level
        {

            BuyProductID(product_10_silver);
        }

        void BuyProductID(string productId)
        {
            if (IsInitialized())
            {
                Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);
                if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
                {
                    Debug.Log(string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));
                   m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
                }
        }

        public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
        {
                   m_StoreController = controller;
                   m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
        }

        public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
        {
               if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, product_10_silver, StringComparison.Ordinal))
               {
                      Debug.Log("You have just bought 10 silver! Good Times");
                      calledscene();
                }
                else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, product_no_ads, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                 {
                        Debug.Log("No Ads");
                  }
          }

        void calledscene()  //here I write a code for unlock level when purchase button click but nothing happens
        {
            int previousBuildIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelCleared");
            int currentBuildIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
            int previouslevelcount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelClearedCount");

            if (currentBuildIndex > previousBuildIndex)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelCleared", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelClearedCount", previouslevelcount + 1);

                print("level cleared count" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelClearedCount"));
            }

            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
```

IapModel.cs

public class IapModel : MonoBehaviour {

```
public void BuySilver10()  //this function call on In-App Purchase Button -> Open Panel -> 11-20Level(Button)press button
{
    IapManager.Instance.Buy10Silver();
}
```

```
Gamemanager.cs

    void Start()  //this script put on menu level button ex: 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc.
    {
        disableALL(); 
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("LevelClearedCount"))      //Hashkey means preferance should be exist or not
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelClearedCount", 0);   
        }

        int clearedLavel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelClearedCount");

        for (int i = 0; i < clearedLavel + 1; ++i)
        {
            transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        }
   }



    public void disableALL()
    {

        int levelButtonsCount = transform.childCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < levelButtonsCount; ++i)
        {
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
        }
    }

Successfinish.cs

void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("LevelCleared")) 
        {

        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelCleared", 0);
        }

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("LevelClearedCount"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelClearedCount", 0);
        }
   }

    public void goNextLevel()  //call this function when my player reaches the roadfinishline then this function call and next means second level(Button) is unlocked.
    {
        //go next level
        int previousBuildIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelCleared");
        int currentBuildIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        int previouslevelcount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelClearedCount");

        if (currentBuildIndex > previousBuildIndex)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelCleared", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelClearedCount", previouslevelcount + 1);

            print("level cleared count" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelClearedCount"));
        }
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
```

Image:

[image]

How to unlock my level when user purchases the 11-20 level then I want to unlock level??

Comment: Please provide more information so we can help you.  What have you tried? Specifically what isn't working?  Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: @Evorlor I edited my question. sorry for the late reply